# Why is my table populating NULL instead of blank?

Tags: sql, null, case-when, isnull

I am trying to figure out why my Eclassification column is still populating NULL instead of a blank value when using the below query in a stored procedure. Originally I just had the Case statement but since that wasn't working I tried adding in the ISNULL as well, but my table will only populate Green or NULL.

```
update ft
set EClassification = case when ft2.hotelsabre = gh.sabre then ISNULL('Green',' ')
else ' ' end
from
fact.travel ft
left join ETL_Framework.Fact.Travel9999 ft2
  on ft.OrigRecnum = ft2.RECNUM
 Join ETL_Gooddata.ETL.GHCAnalysis gh 
  on ft2.hotelsabre = gh.sabre
  where travel_type_id = 3 
  and
createdate >= @LoadDate
and invoicedate between @StartDate and @EndDate
--and datasourceid = @DataSourceID
and ft.datasourceid in (select d.DataSourceID from Dim.DataSource d 
--left join ETL.LoadConfig c on d.DataSourceID = c.DataSourceID where case when d.DataSourceID in (2,3) then 1 else c.DataSourceID end = @DataSourceID)
left join ETL.LoadConfig c on d.DataSourceID = c.DataSourceID 
where case when d.DataSourceID in (2,3) then 1 
           when d.DataSourceID in (11,14) then 11
else c.DataSourceID end = @DataSourceID)
```

When I select from the table that the above stored procedure updates, my EClassification column is only 'Green' or NULL, not 'Green' or blank.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [FactTravelID]
    ,ft.[DataSourceID]
      ,[TravelTypeID]  
     ,[TransactionID]
      ,[InvoiceDate]
      ,ft.[AHC]
      ,[AirMiscData1]
      ,[AirMiscData2]
      ,hotelsabre
      ,[EClassification]
      ,hotelsabre
  FROM [ETL_Gooddata].[Fact].[Travel] ft
  join ETL_Framework.Fact.Travel9999 ft2
  on  ft.OrigRecnum = ft2.recnum
 
  where TravelTypeID = 3 
  and CreateDate > '2021-06-13'
```

Comment: Populating what into where?  Sample data and results would be a big help, as would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just added more information.

Comment: Why are you comparing ft2.hotelsabre = gh.sabre when they're part of the join?  Also, ISNULL('Green'," ") will never return blank because 'Green' will never be null.

Comment: @Duston Green is NULL when hotelsabre  and sabre do not match. Hotel sabre has 10,000+ possible unique values and sabre only has a handful. If sabre does not have a match with hotel sabre, then it should print blank..

Answer (score 0):

StackOverFlow vets, still new to this.  Be gentle...You're using a LEFT JOIN to ETL_Framework.Fact.Travel9999 and an INNER JOIN to ETL_Gooddata.ETL.GHCAnalysis and your ON clause is the same condition as your CASE statement evaluation. Try using a LEFT JOIN to [ETL_Gooddata].[ETL].[GHCAnalysis].

```
UPDATE ft
SET EClassification = CASE WHEN ft2.hotelsabre = gh.sabre THEN ISNULL('Green',' ') ELSE ' ' END
FROM [fact].[travel] ft
LEFT JOIN [ETL_Framework].[Fact].[Travel9999] ft2
    ON ft.OrigRecnum = ft2.RECNUM
LEFT JOIN [ETL_Gooddata].[ETL].[GHCAnalysis] gh  
    ON ft2.hotelsabre = gh.sabre
WHERE travel_type_id = 3 
    AND createdate >= @LoadDate
    AND invoicedate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND ft.datasourceid IN (SELECT d.DataSourceID 
                        FROM [Dim].[DataSource] d 
                        LEFT JOIN [ETL].[LoadConfig] c 
                            ON d.DataSourceID = c.DataSourceID 
                        WHERE CASE WHEN d.DataSourceID in (2,3) THEN 1 
                                   WHEN d.DataSourceID in (11,14) THEN 11
                                   ELSE c.DataSourceID END = @DataSourceID)
```